# no data showing in query results

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So i have a database with a categories table in it. There are 6 categories within this table (Power, Logic, Sensors, Safety, Operator Interface, Connection Devices)

Im trying to make a drop down within my top navigation to display these categories. I thought i could do it with a simple SELECT query grabbing the categories and displaying them in the drop down. This way in the future if more categories are added they will automatically go into the navigation.

However My data isnt appearing in the menu, but 6 blank areas where the data should be are there.

Here is my SQL.

```
$mysql_connection = db_connect_enhanced('XXXXX','dbaccess','brother','website');    //Connect to database
        $categories = "SELECT * FROM rockwell.RAE_categories WHERE active = 1";
        $result = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $categories);
        $count = count($result);
```

and here is the HTML and PHP to display the menu

```
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?=$base?>"><img src="images/nav-home.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#.php"><img src="images/nav-products.jpg"></a>
                <ul>
                    <?for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
                    {?>
                        <?$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);?>
                        <li><a class="dropDown" href="#"><?$row['categoryName']?></a></li>
                    <?}?>
                </ul>                                               
            </li>
            <li><a href="faq.php"><img src="images/nav-faq.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#.php"><img src="images/nav-contact.jpg"></a></li>
            <li class="end"><a href="#.php"><img src="images/nav-delivery.jpg"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: the fact that there are 6 bar printed out means you are in the right way. You can try `print_r()` your `$row` to see whether you have used  correct indexes

Comment: what is the value for count?

Comment: the value for count is 6

Comment: Then your query runs successfully, you have to loop correctly. follow @Rikesh answer

Comment: I used print_r() and it does display all the data from the database correctly. Which makes my problem even more confusing :-/

Comment: you need to have while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop to get your data.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       //Your code
}
```

Also replace

```
<?$row['categoryName']?>
```

by

```
<?=$row['categoryName']?>
```

Comment: have you checked whether you are getting the any data in $result? why don't you try var_dump() or print_r()

Comment: @Sephiroth - Can you check & post what you get using `var_dump($row);` inside your loop ?

Comment: I get nothing putting it inside the while loop the drop down doesnt appear. But if i put it beneath the SQL statement I get this......6array(6) { [0]=> array(3) { ["categoryID"]=> string(1) "2" ["categoryName"]=> string(5) "Power" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(3) { ["categoryID"]=> string(1) "4" ["categoryName"]=> string(5) "Logic" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(3) { ["categoryID"]=> string(1) "6" ["categoryName"]=> string(18) "Operator Interface" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" } [3]=> array(3) { ["categoryID"]=> string(1) "8 ...... Ran out of characters to post

Comment: I should add its not the styling of the drop down. Because previously it was hard coded and It worked ok. Its just this dynamic method has thrown it out of wack

Comment: @Sephiroth - Seems `db_query_into_array_enhanced` method is playing game here. The above array you posted in comment is of `$result` or `$row` ?

Comment: well when i tried it in the loop it was of $row...but it displayed nothing..so when i put it beneath the SQL statement i changed it to $result

Comment: @Sephiroth - Ok than you need `$result[$i]["categoryName"]` in your loop.

Comment: i've changed from a for loop to a while loop. do I still use $I? my code now reads............."<ul>
       <?while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {?>
        <li><a class="dropDown" href="#"><?=$row['categoryName'];?></a></li>
       <?}?>
      </ul> "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29360/discussion-between-rikesh-and-sephiroth)

Answer (score 0):

This line does not print out anything because of the missing `echo` statement:

```
<li><a class="dropDown" href="#"><?$row['categoryName']?></a></li>
```

Instead use this:

```
 <li><a class="dropDown" href="#"><?php echo $row['categoryName']?></a></li>
```

Comment: yeah I just noticed that before I read your comment so I fixed that...but still no change, my code now reads:

<?while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {?>
        <li><a class="dropDown" href="#"><?=$row['categoryName'];?></a></li>
       <?}?>

Comment: I assume you do have the "short tags" enabled?

Comment: yeah i do have that enabled

Comment: have you tried `print_r($row)` to see if it actually contains a field `categoryName`?